# Redundant feature after one hot encoding

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, logistic-regression

I have a numerical feature called $x$ and a categorical feature called $y$.
$y$ is an ordinal feature (A,B,C,D,E,F).
I am using label encoding for my y feature and when I am seeing the correlation using matrix heatmap it shows that my $x$ feature has 0.95 correlation with $y$. I am using logistic regression algorithm.
Should I drop one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should drop one of them. It is not a good idea to have highly correlated features in a logistic regression model. You should be able to see the model's accuracy improve after the drop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).